# React Library - Attempted import error: 'XXX' is not exported from

Tags: reactjs, next.js, rollup

I built a React library and exported it with rollup. When importing into a Nextjs project I get the message `Attempted import error: 'Heading' is not exported from`. But when I look at the build of the component library, the component is exported:

```
import { ComponentProps, FC } from "react";
export interface HeadingProps extends ComponentProps<'span'> {
    title?: string;
    type?: 'h1' | 'h2';
}
export declare const Heading: FC<HeadingProps>;
```

What could be the reason that I get this error when building the Next project?

Build Component Library with Rollup

Comment: Code you show is typescript declarations, not an actual module. It's possible for TS declarations to not match module source code. You need to check if Heading is exported from actual module (js file)